# Take Data using XML and save it to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, visual-studio-2010, dataset

I have this situation, I want to take data from another computer that connected to my computer,
 my database connection using OLEDB. 
I want to take that data using XML and save it to my SQL SERVER database and show it either to my website .aspx
I've been told that I can do that with Dataset -> XML -> SQL Server, is that correct? 
What I suppose to do?

Comment: It is hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do. Can you define the exact problem you are currently having? What have you tried? What do you mean by "I want to take data from another computer that connected to my computer". Answering questions like this will prompt people to give better suggestions / solutions.

Comment: You can pass the XML as a string to an prepared insert using SqlCommand, as a parameter of type SqlDbType.Xml

Comment: @Despertar , the original database are from computer1, i'm using computer2 and I want to take that data using xml, the database connection using OLEDB.

Comment: What is your Datasource? Access database?

Comment: If computer2 can query computer1 why would you convert it to XML? That sounds like an extra step that isn't necessary. Why can't you query the database then insert the data directly into your local sql database?

Comment: @Derek , its not access database its from machine that store some data using some software, but connecting using OLEDB, I just working on the client side

Comment: @Despertar , I have to show it in my website either, I heard that its more fast than stored it in sql and call it again to my website. Because the data have thousands of rows. For example, I need to SUM the data first and then stored it, thats why I need using xml, so I dont have to stored to much data in my sql server

Comment: Right, so you want to store XML in SQl yes? You should pherhaps look at XML Serialsation / De-serialsation.

Comment: Depends how the website is accessing the data. If the website is calling accessing the data via an AJAX request then yes it would need to be serialized into XML or JSON anyways to be sent over the wire. However even in this case the clients should only be able to request so much data at a time (10/20/50 items at a time) which is where paging comes in. ASP.NET Web API and ASP.NET MVC4 both have extensive support for this type of operation and handle all the serialization for you (converting the data to and from xml). In this sense, there is no issue with just storing the data naturally.

Comment: @Despertar I need to SUM the data using xml before I stored it, I can't just stored it all in my sql server. I need to process it first before i stored it

Comment: "Because the data have thousands of rows.", @user2063311 what are you really trying to do? And it also seems that we have a language issue here, maybe you could try reposting your question in a forum of your native language?